# SQL: Find percentage of tasks completed based on the status

Tags: sql, oracle, percentage

I have a table that lists the tasks along with a label to indicate if they are completed or not. The table looks like this:

### Task | Status

```
Task1 | Done

Task2 | Done

Task3 | Not done

Task4 | Done

Task5 | Not done
```

I'm trying to come up with a query that will list the percentage of completed tasks and the output should look like this:

### Total Tasks | Completed | Completed %

```
        5     |       3       |      60%
```

The problem I'm facing is I'm not able to figure out how to count the completed and not completed tasks to find the percentage.

Comment: what sql language are you using? add a tag

Comment: Include what you tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COUNT` function to find the total count. Then find the count of completed using a combination of `SUM` function and `CASE` expression. And using these 2 values, find the percentage of completed.

**Query**

```
select t.TotalTask, t.Completed, 
(cast(t.Completed as float) / cast(t.TotalTask as float)) * 100 as CompletedPercentage 
from (
        select count(task) as TotalTask
        , sum(case status when 'Done' then 1 else 0 end) as Completed
        from your_table_name
) as t;
```

**[Find a demo here](http://rextester.com/YOII34237)**

Comment: Worked on the first go. Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You can do conditional aggregation `completed

```
select totaltask, completed,  100 * completed / totaltask as CompletedPercentage 
from (select count(*) as totaltask, 
             sum(case when status = 'Done' then 1 else 0 end) as completed
      from table
      ) t;
```

Comment: make sure to cast a division parameter to a float

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis - Oracle NUMBER handles division just fine, no need to cast to FLOAT

Comment: ah, didn't notice the oracle tag, sorry